# Downloading audio from dynamic URLs in React using fetch and blob

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React application where users can download audio files from dynamic URLs. These URLs are fetched from an external API and can vary in length and content. I'm using the fetch API to retrieve the audio data and create Blob objects for downloading. However, I'm encountering issues with fetching and downloading audio files from URLs starting with "https://rr2---sn-npbopo-aixe.googlevideo.com".

**Problem:**

When attempting to fetch audio data using fetch with these dynamic URLs, I'm not able to successfully download the audio files. I think all array map to same button

```js
const downloadBlob = async (audiourl,index) => {
    try {
      const blobresponse = await fetch(audiourl,{ mode: 'no-cors' });
      const blob = await blobresponse.blob();
      const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = blobURL;
      a.download = `audio_${index}.mp3`; 
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Blob download error:', error);
    }
  };
```

The audio files retrieved from these URLs need to be downloaded to the user's device with appropriate filenames.

```js
(5) ['https://rr2---sn-npbopo-aixe.googlevideo.com/video', 'https://rr2---sn-npbopo-aixe.googlevideo.com/video', 'https://rr2---sn-npbopo-aixe.googlevideo.com/video', 'https://rr2---sn-npbopo-aixe.googlevideo.com/video', 'https://rr2---sn-npbopo-aixe.googlevideo.com/video']
0
: 
"https://rr2---sn-npbopo-aixe.googlevideo.com/video"
1
: 
"https://rr2---sn-npbopo-aixe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1707237"
2
: 
"https://rr2---sn-npbopo-aixe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1707237932&ei=zA3CZdvcGbqhmLAPoee3sAE&ip=111.88.76.41&id=o-AEQChom"
3
: 
"
4
: 
"https://rr2---sn-npbopo-aixe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1707237932&ei=zA3CZdvcGbqhmLAPoee3sAE&ip=111.88.76.41&id="
length
: 
5
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```

**API RESPONSE BE LIKE**

Question:

How can I modify my code to effectively fetch and download audio files from dynamic URLs starting with "https://rr2---sn-npbopo-aixe.googlevideo.com" using the fetch API in a React application?

NOTE: API DATA IS FETCH BEFORE. IT IS PART OF THAT DATA AND USE FETCH TO CREATE BLOB FOR THAT URLS

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 {onlyaudio.map((option, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td className='text-center p-4'>{option.abr}</td>
              <td className='text-center p-4 '>{option.mime_type}</td>
              <td className="text-amber-400 text-center p-4">✓</td>
              <td className='text-center p-4'>{option.filesize_mb} MB</td>
              <td>
                <a
                  className="rounded-md bg-amber-400 px-3 py-2 border-1 border-dashed border-white text-sm font-semibold text-black shadow-sm hover:bg-yellow-600/80 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-yellow-600"
                  onClick={() => downloadBlob(option.url,index)}
                  download
                  
                  
                  >
                  Download
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
```